# How to count individual user records in a database table

Tags: php, laravel, database

I am new to Laravel, and I am working on a project where I want to count rows for each user in the database table to display in view.

### Error:

```
Attempt to read property "location" on int (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project104\resources\views\users\show.blade.php)
```

### Code:

```
 @foreach($users as $user)  
        <div class="d-inline p-2">
            <div class="col"> 
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div style="margin-left:310px"><img class="card-img-top" style="height:4rem" src="{{url('/img/logo1.jpg')}}" alt="Card image cap"></div>
                        <div class="rounded-pill" style="width: 75px; height: 30px; background-color: #131c2d; color: #3490dc; text-align: center;"><span><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:#3490dc;"></i></span>{{$user->id}} </div>
                        <hr color=131c2d>
                        <div style="text-align: center;" class="card-body">

                        <h6 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{$user->name}}</h6>
                        <br/>
                        <small><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{$user->organization}}</small>
                        <br/>
                        <!--$user = App\User::withCount('kinds')->find();-->
                        {{$user = DB::table('kinds')->count()}}
                        <br/>
                        <small><small><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{$user->location}}</small> </small><br/><hr color=3490dc>
                        <small style="color:#3490dc;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i></small> <small style="color:#3490dc;"> joined {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</small></small>
                     
                        </div>
                    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
@endforeach
```

This is the code snippet I am trying to count with:

```
{{$user = DB::table('kinds')->count()}}
```

Comment: You used `count()`, so `$user` is an integer, not a collection or array. You're overwriting the original `$user` with that query, so I would actually suggest using a different variable name. Since you're not restricting the query, I wouldn't suggest doing it in the loop, because you'll be checking it every single loop. Instead, it should be in the controller and passed along.

Comment: Don't put database queries in the view and DEFINITELY not inside a loop.  Prepare your data in the controller.  Add `withCount('kinds')` in the query where you fetch the users, then each user will have a `kinds_count` attribute.   https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Answer (score 1):

If your `$users`, used in your foreach loop, is `$users = App\User::withCount('kinds')->get();` from the controller where "kinds" is the name of the relation declared on the User::class, then you just need to access the count on it with `$user->kinds_count`

```html
@foreach($users as $user)  
    <div class="d-inline p-2">
        <div class="col"> 
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div>
                    <img class="card-img-top" style="height:4rem" src="{{url('/img/logo1.jpg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
                </div>
                <div class="rounded-pill">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:#3490dc;"></i></span>
                    {{$user->id}}
                </div>
                <hr color=131c2d>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> 
                        {{$user->name}}
                    </h6>
                    <br/>
                    <small>
                        <i class="fa fa-building-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> 
                        {{$user->organization}}
                    </small>
                    <br/>

                    {{$user->kinds_count}} <!--This is what you're looking for-->

                    <br/>
                    <small><small> <!--Double tag for nothing-->
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc;"></i>
                        {{$user->location}}
                    </small></small>
                    <br/>
                    <hr color=3490dc>
                    <small>
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    </small>
                    <small>
                        joined {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
                    </small>

                    </small><!--You have an extra closing tag here you should remove it-->
                     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
@endforeach
```